# WooCommerce Category identical H1 and title tag

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a question about WooCommerce. SEMrush tells me my category page contains identical H1 and title tag. How and where can I change that? I´m using WordPress.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: Could you paste here the warning/error you are getting?

Comment: The content of the H1 tag on this page is the same as the page title...

Comment: TO THIS PROBLEM

Do not use the same content for the title tag and H1 header. Identical <title> and <h1> tags can be considered as over-optimized by search engines.
If the title and headline are the same, you'll also miss a chance to include more relevant keywords for your page.